# Minimize SQL Statements? - Stack SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress Plugin script which extends the plugin. So, my problem is, I have to deal with the database which is pretty inefficient because I have only the first normal form...

This is the reason, why I'm forced to get the values like this:

```
$details = $database->query("SELECT `meta_key`, `meta_value` FROM `6v8T0_postmeta` WHERE post_id = '$pid' AND (meta_key like '$price_meta' OR meta_key like '$price_old_meta' OR meta_key like '$link_meta' OR meta_key like '$shop_meta')");

        while($row_meta = $details->fetch_assoc()){
            if($row_meta["meta_key"] == $price_meta){
                $price = $row_meta["meta_value"];
            }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $price_old_meta){
                $price_old = $row_meta["meta_value"];
            }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $link_meta){
                $link = $row_meta["meta_value"];
            }elseif($row_meta["meta_key"] == $shop_meta){
                $shop = $row_meta["meta_value"];
            }else{
                fwrite($myfile, "Is not matching!\n");
            }
        }
```

1. My question now is, what is $database->query returning? 
   Because I want to minimize my SQL queries I want to load all values I need in a two dimensional array and sort them afterwords.

Is that possible and if yes, how?

2. Stack SQL queries? - I say multiple times Select, Delete and Insert in a loop. Is it possible to stack those statements and execute one query instant of 4? - And if yes, can I continue in my code with `fetch_assoc()` normally? - Because I'm not sure if this is possible if I stack Delete, Insert and Select...
3. Are there any other ways to minimize SQL queries?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Just for anyone else who comes by $database isn't the wordpress database object. It's a mysqli object.

Answer (score 1):

First the database structure isn't inefficient, it's a widely used and accepted pattern of storing a list of key/value pairs in the database.

There are two ways you can improve the situation for yourself.

> MAPPING ARRAY

This one is probably going to be your best choice, as it's very flexible and doesn't require you to change your queries.

```
$details = $database->prepare("
    SELECT
        `meta_key`,
        `meta_value`
    FROM
        `6v8T0_postmeta`
    WHERE
        post_id = '$pid'
        AND meta_key IN (
            %s,
            %s,
            %s,
            %s
        )
    ",
    array(
        $price_meta,
        $price_old_meta,
        $link_meta,
        $shop_meta
   )
);

$map = array();

while($row_meta = $details->fetch_assoc()){
    $map[$row_meta['meta_key']] = $row_meta['meta_value'];
}

/*

$map will look something like this

array(
    'price' => '10.99',
    'price_old' => '9.99',
    'link' => 'http://example.org/awesome-product',
    'shop' => 'main'
)

*/

$price = array_key_exists($price_meta, $map) ? $map[$price_meta] : 'default value';
$price_old = array_key_exists($price_old_meta, $map) ? $map[$price_old_meta] : 'default value';
$link = array_key_exists($link_meta, $map) ? $map[$link_meta] : 'default value';
$shop = array_key_exists($shop_meta, $map) ? $map[$shop_meta] : 'default value';
```

> JOINS

This method makes your query long and needs you to update it everytime you want a new field added.

```
$details = $database->prepare("
    SELECT
        b.meta_value %s,
        c.meta_value %s,
        d.meta_value %s,
        e.meta_value %s
    FROM
        `6v8T0_postmeta` a
    LEFT JOIN
        `6v8T0_postmeta` b ON
            b.post_id = a.post_id
            AND b.meta_key = %s
    LEFT JOIN
        `6v8T0_postmeta` c ON
            c.post_id = a.post_id
            AND c.meta_key = %s
    LEFT JOIN
        `6v8T0_postmeta` d ON
            d.post_id = a.post_id
            AND d.meta_key = %s
    LEFT JOIN
        `6v8T0_postmeta` e ON
            e.post_id = a.post_id
            AND e.meta_key = %s
    WHERE
        a.post_id = '$pid'
    ",
    array(
        $price_meta,
        $price_old_meta,
        $link_meta,
        $shop_meta,
        $price_meta,
        $price_old_meta,
        $link_meta,
        $shop_meta,
        $price_meta,
        $price_old_meta,
        $link_meta,
        $shop_meta
    )
);

$map = array();

if (!($row_meta = $details->fetch_assoc())) {
    $price = $row_meta[$price_meta];
    $price_old = $row_meta[$price_old_meta];
    $link = $row_meta[$link_meta];
    $shop = $row_meta[$shop_meta];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your long answer! :) - But I have some questions. I never worked with mapped arrays. I have a lot of entries value pairs with the tag `$price_meta`, `$link_meta` and so on. So, the different think is to keep those values together which belongs together.. Is this working with your code? This is the reason why I said, I would need a two dimensional array... And what does `?` and `: 'default value';` mean?

Comment: And I forgot the `%s`. For what is that?

Comment: `$var = condition ? true : false;` is what's known as a ternary operator, it's like doing `if ($var) { true } else { false }` just much shorter. [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: For %s review the documentation on wordpress [Code Reference wpdb::prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

Comment: I updated the answer to include an example of what `$map` will look like.

Comment: If I try to use your code I get `Method call uses 5 parameters, but method signature uses 1 parameters`

Comment: sounds like you're still using query and not prepare.

Comment: I use your code (copy & paste): `$details = $database->prepare("SELECT 'meta_key', 'meta_value' FROM '6v8T0_postmeta' WHERE post_id = '$pid' AND meta_key IN (%s, %s, %s, %s)", $price_meta, $price_old_meta, $link_meta, $shop_meta);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140014/discussion-between-augwa-and-fraze-jr).